# A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm creating microcms app using nuxt3.
And I bumped into the error which I wrote in title.
I know it might be component problem, but I can't figure out why.
Here's the code.

pages/list.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
        <div>
            <h1 class="m-3 text-4xl font-bold">当店のレビュー一覧</h1>
        </div>
        <ReviewList :reviews="reviews.contents" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    const {data:reviews} = await useFetch('/api/reviewList')
</script>
```

components/ReviewList.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    import { Review } from '../types/review'

    const header = ref(["number", "title"])

    type Props = {
        reviews: Review[];
    }

    const { reviews } = defineProps<Props>()
</script>

<template>
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="p-1" v-for="col in header">{{ col }}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="hover:bg-green-200" v-for="(review, index) in reviews">
                <th class="p-1">{{ index+1 }}</th>
                <nuxt-link :to="`/${review.id}`">
                    <td class="p-1">{{ review.title }}</td>
                </nuxt-link>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

types/review.ts

```
import type { MicroCMSListContent } from "microcms-js-sdk";

export type Review = {
    title: string;
    body: string;
} & MicroCMSListContent;
```

server/api/reviewlist.ts

```
import client from './client'
import { Review } from '../../types/review'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const data = await client
        .getList<Review>({
            endpoint: 'reviews',
        })
    return data
})
```

server/api/client.ts

```
import { createClient } from 'microcms-js-sdk';

const ctx = useRuntimeConfig();

const client = createClient({
    serviceDomain: ctx.serviceDomain,
    apiKey: ctx.apiKey,
});

export default client
```

What's wrong? Please tell me how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figure it out.

```
<script>
    const {data:reviews} = await useFetch('/api/reviewList')
</script>
```

When I changed the code above to below, it works.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    const {data:reviews} = await useFetch('/api/reviewList')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I'm going to show you how to fix the problem using `useFetch()` is a composable method.

```
watch(router,(value) => {
  useFetch("/list");
})
```

Afterwards, I had to use:

```
const LoadPage = () => {
  useFetch("/list");
}
```

------  how to fix methods ---

`loadPage` go to the top to view and call again

```
watch(router,(value) => {
  loadPage();
})
```

This article helped me understand the reason why using a function of composable is wrong position